# How can I make events based on the active window? (python)

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I make it so that when a certain window is active, the resolution is 1440x1080, but if any other window is active the resolution is 1920x1080 in Python?

(the comments are on purpose)
I'm using tkinter and I've tried:

```
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

if tk.ACTIVE('notepad.exe') *res changing command*
else *res changing command*

# def setresEvent(event):
    

def startwinexpEvent(event):
    subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\\VBucks\\Workspaces\\winexp\\winexp.exe'])

#setRes = tk.Button(
   # text='Click me!',
   # height=28,
   # width=32,
   # bg='black',
   # fg='white',
#)
# setRes.bind('<Button-1>', setresEvent)
#setRes.pack()

startwinExp = tk.Button(
    text='Start winexp',
    height=28,
    width=32,
    bg='black',
    fg='white',
)
startwinExp.bind('<Button-WinExp>', startwinexpEvent)
startwinExp.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "resolution"? Are you wanting the program to actively tell the OS to switch the resolution of the monitor?

Comment: But what is this? if tk.ACTIVE('notepad.exe') *res changing command*

Comment: I need to change the screen resolution if a certain window is active and I don't know how to change the screen resolution in python, hence the "res changing command". I also don't know how to determine if a certain window is active.